# Google news feed url doesn't work with Google feed API

Tags: jquery, google-feed-api, google-news

If I use following URL with Google feed api, it doesn't work;

http://news.google.co.in/news?hl=en&gl=in&q=something&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=atom

OR

http://news.google.co.in/news?hl=en&gl=in&q=something&um=1&ie=UTF-8&output=rss

it gives me null. However rss of any other site works perfectly. I am using jGFeed for this.

```
(function($){
  $.extend({
    jGFeed : function(url, fnk, num, key){
      // Make sure url to get is defined
      if(url == null) return false;
      // Build Google Feed API URL
      var gurl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&callback=?&q="+url;
      if(num != null) gurl += "&num="+num;
      if(key != null) gurl += "&key="+key;
      // AJAX request the API
      $.getJSON(gurl, function(data){
        if(typeof fnk == 'function')
                  fnk.call(this, data.responseData.feed);
                else
                  return false;
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Whats wrong I am attempting?